# How to change max number of column in VS code text editor - Linux

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, word-wrap, text-editor

I am new to Ubuntu. i am using vs code for dart. The max number of columns for the default editor would apparently be 80: what I would like to change or disable.
Image that describe what I'm saying

[image]

I am trying the solutions on google like :
**editor.wordWrap: "wordWrapColumn"**

Source: [the solutions that i tried](https://prograide.com/pregunta/54686/comment-activer-lhabillage-du-texte-par-defaut-dans-vs-code)

But it not work.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Open your setting and search for `Dart Line Length` and increase the number.

[image]

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more  on [dartcode](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/)